# Switch case Different Types with go

Tags: go, switch-statement

The following program doesn't compile due to type mismatch error(int vs bool)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 5
    switch i {
    case 4:
        fmt.Println("4")
    case i > 8:
        fmt.Println("i is greator than 8")
    }
}
```

As someone from Dynamic Typing background, this the above is bit of a culture shock. so wondering what's the idiomatic way do this in GO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a generic switch:

```
func main() {
    i := 5
    switch {
    case i == 4:
        fmt.Println("4")
    case i > 8:
        fmt.Println("i is greator than 8")
    default: 
        fmt.Printf("i = (%v), i != 4 && i <= 8\n", i)
    }
}
```